# Why this sql code throws error

Tags: mysql, sql

I have an SQL code for calculating rank on the leaderboard from won matches and the played matches:

```
SELECT count(1) 
FROM `account` 
WHERE points < SELECT points FROM (SELECT `display name`, 3*`wins`-`matches played` AS points FROM `account`) AS T WHERE `display name` = "valaki"
```

The left part of the inequality is working if I change the points for wins or any existing field, the left part of it works as well, but the code doesn't works.

Comment: What's the error message?

Answer (score 1):

You need parentheses around subqueries:

```
SELECT count(1)
FROM account a
WHERE a.points < (SELECT 3*a2.wins-a2.matchesplayed AS points
                  FROM account a2
                  WHERE a2.displayname = 'valaki'
                 );
```

In addition, you are referring to columns as `matches played` and `diplay name`.  That is not correct.  You need escape characters around column names with spaces.  My advice is to fix the column names, so they don't need to be escaped.

I also added table aliases.  These are a good habit.  They really should be mandatory if a query references more than one table or has more than one `FROM` clause.